# Обслуживание бд на продакшене?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, backend, развертывание

Я развернул бэкенд на ubuntu 20.04, установил субд, установил все зависимости для бэка, в общем всё работает. Так же субд например находится по адресу example.com:5050, к примеру логин там root и пароль root, много кто может пароль и логин угадать, так вот вопрос как обычно поступают с субд ?

1 - делают пароль и логин более сложными что бы никто не знал ?

2 - например на данный адрес ограничивают доступ ? example.com:5050

или как ? кто-то может подсказать как более правильно это делать ?

Comment: Не открывают доступ во внешний мир вообще :) только по локальной сети, либо через кластер.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.